# Python Multiprocessing - Can we pass an (itertools.islice) iterable directly to pool.imap whithout converting to a list?

Tags: python, multithreading, iterator, multiprocessing, generator

After reading a large table from DB2 (some tables have 100 million) in chunks, I convert the generator object to iterator using itertools.islice. I pass the iterator to multiprocessing pool.map that calls a function to extract these chunks to CSV parallely.

It works but before the parallel run starts, python pool.map converts the ITERATOR to a LIST that consumes lot of time. Is there a way I can avoid this list creation or convert into list faster? I also tried using POOL.IMAP but my notebook kernel dies when I run the program. To use IMAP, I will have to convert the iterator to a list which takes time again. Any thoughts?

```
generator_df = pd.read_sql(query2, test_connection_forbankcv_connection, chunksize = 5000)
iterable_slice = list(it.islice(generator_df, slice_start,slice_end))
results = p.imap(chunk_to_csv, iterable_slice, 1)
```

Comment: Would you consider using Spark? Pyspark if you prefer python. It will make your life easier.

Comment: The source of `_map_async` indicates that it requires the passed `iterable` to have a `__len__` attribute, and if it doesn't, it converts it to a list. All the `map` variants appear to delegate to that method, so there doesn't appear to be a way around it. You may be able to rig something up with `apply_async` where you're handling the iterable yourself.

Comment: @Carcigenicate. Hope hard would it be to implement an iterator with `__len__`?

Comment: That the “notebook kernel dies” is not very informative.  What exactly happens—preferably tested in a Python process that isn’t hidden inside a GUI?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I suppose that in this particular case, you could make a wrapper over a slice object that exposes a length attribute since the length could be calculated. In general though, iterators can be infinite, so a length may not make sense.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This makes sense. If I can calculate the length of the iterable, as you mentioned can we make a wrapper over a slice object?.How to do that? Do you have an example? Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you so much. Can we pass the iterable to pool.imap directly without converting as a list? As far as i know, pool.imap does not convert the iterable to a list and that could be a time saver. Thoughts on pool.imap?

Comment: @Bala Actually, I take back what I had said before. `_get_tasks` *does* use `islice` and `tuple` to force part of the collection, but only a chunk at a time, and it creates the chunks lazily. I've undeleted my answer, and it actually does appear that it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit right off the bat, this solution has a few problems, but it shows the basic idea:

```
import itertools
from typing import Iterable
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Lengthed_ISlice:
    def __init__(self, iterable: Iterable, start: int, stop: int):
        self._start = start
        self._stop = stop
        self._islice = itertools.islice(iterable, self._start, self._stop)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._stop - self._start

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._islice)
```

This is a thin wrapper over an `islice` object that implements the required `__len__` method so that it will work with `Pool`'s `map` method:

```
def double(n):
    return n * 2

my_list = list(range(10, 100))

with Pool() as p:
    print(p.map(double, Lengthed_ISlice(my_list, 2, 9)))
    # Prints [24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36]
```

Main issues:

- It doesn't properly delegate any functionality to the underlying `islice` except for `__iter__`. If you get errors about missing methods when/if you expand your usage of this, you'll need to implement the proper methods.
- For brevity, I didn't bother with steps since you aren't using non-default steps, and they complicate the math a tiny bit.
- I didn't worry about making use of `Iterable`'s generic parameter. If you want better type hinting, you should introduce a `TypeVar` for the constructor argument and for `__iter__`.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. I will try and let you know.